# Compress data before transfer between Spring application and MongoDB server

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

A list of big documents need to be transferred between my Spring Boot application and MongoDB server. How to config the MongoDB server and the Spring application to compress the data before the transmission?

MongoDB version is 4.2

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Storage engine does support different configuration for compression, for more information follow below link.
https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/coming-in-42-compression-key-rotation-and-configuration

But there is no such configuration to compress the document before transmission.

Not sure with your use case but from SpringBoot application you can compress the data and store it as a compressed document in MongoDB and uncompress in application after reading from MongoDB.